# Media query to shrink Ionic >=2 alert not working on IOS

Tags: css, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have found that the [Ionic alert](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#alert) does not seem to adjust it's height when we go into `landscape`, so if I have many options it is too high on most phones if put into landscape.

To get around this I added the following media query...

```
    @media screen and (max-height: 350px) {
          .alert-md .alert-radio-group,
          .alert-md .alert-checkbox-group {
            max-height: 140px;
          }
      }
```

This seemed to work fine on `Android`, but not at all on `iOS`. I have viewed the app running on the device in Safari, and can see that it element in question does have the `alert-radio-group`applied, but I do not see the media query applied (and it has the original height which is too high)

The Ionic app viewport is set to

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

which looks correct according to other posts.

Also, I am slightly confused about the what is width and what is height in **landscape mode** (does width and height swap so is the width now the longest side, I am assuming so). At any rate it works on `Android`.

Does anyone have any idea why this is not working on `iOS` (>= 10), or perhaps a better way of auto resizing the alert box.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using android specific classes `alert-md`. In case of `ios` the class generated would be `alert-ios`

```
@media screen and (max-height: 350px) {
      .alert-md .alert-radio-group,
      .alert-md .alert-checkbox-group,
      .alert-ios .alert-radio-group,
      .alert-ios .alert-checkbox-group {
        max-height: 140px;
      }
  }
```

Comment: great that fixed it! I actually thought the `.alert-radio-group` was enough but that was not the case. We also need the ios classes,